# Error al agregar la librería session en el archivo autoload.php

Tags: codeigniter-3

Voy iniciar a desarrollar un login en CodeIgniter, pasé a descargar los archivos y los he instalado en mi servidor portables.
Pero al cargar la librería 'session' en el archivo autoload.php me da el siguiente error. 
¿Porqué? :/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo config.php:

En esta parte:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = FALSE;
```

Debe quedar así:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```